# settimeout not working properly when i tried to use it to refresh a page

Tags: javascript, refresh, settimeout, userscripts, tampermonkey

The purpose of this code is to refresh a page after either a wait time of 1 second or 5 seconds depending on a random variable. However, the code below makes it so that it either refreshes after a wait time of 1 second EVERY SINGLE TIME, or it refreshes after a wait time of 5 seconds EVERY SINGLE TIME.

How do I make it so that the refresh wait time are EITHER 1 second OR 5 seconds on every refresh?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        google.com
// @namespace   John Galt
// @description Basic Google Hello
// @match       *^https://www.google.com/$*
// @version     1
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==

//*****************************************START OF SET_TIMEOUT
(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  var interval;
  if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0) { interval = 1000; }
  else { interval = 5000; }
  if (window == window.top) {
    var body = $('body').empty();
    var myframe = $('<iframe>')
      .attr({ src: location.href })
      .css({ height: '95vh', width: '100%' })
      .appendTo(body)
      .on('load', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
          myframe.attr({ src: location.href });
        }, interval);
      });
  }
})(jQuery);
//*****************************************END OF SET_TIMEOUT
```

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've edited the code, and tried putting it inside, but it's still not working properly. Did I put it in the wrong place?

Comment: The issue is that while you are pointing the `iframe` to the current document, the document that contains the `iframe` is only being loaded once (and that's why you are seeing the same interval being used over and over) and when the `iframe` loads the same file up inside of it, the value that it generates for `interval` is not the same one as is controlling the loading of the `iframe`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Oh. So is there a way to fix it so it changes?

Comment: Let me ask, what is the reason you are loading the current page into an `iframe`, rather than just reloading the current page in the same window?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Oh. The reason I'm using the iFrame is because sometimes when I refresh the page it gives me the 503 status error, and if it gives me the 503 status error then the script stops running. I'm able to keep the script running even when it hits the 503 error when I'm using the iframe.

Comment: I think you should just do an AJAX request for the current file inside of your `setTimeout`. That way you can handle a server error by just doing the AJAX call again. This would be way simpler. No `iframe`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm not sure how to write such a code. Can you write a short example code that we can test on google.com?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show just that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that while you are pointing the `iframe` to the current document, the document that contains the `iframe` is only being loaded once (and that's why you are seeing the same interval being used over and over) and when the `iframe` loads the same file up inside of it, the value that it generates for interval is not the same one as is controlling the loading of the `iframe`.

I think you should just do an AJAX request for the current file inside of your `setTimeout`. That way you can handle a server error by just doing the AJAX call again. This would be way simpler. No `iframe`.

```js
(function ($) {
 'use strict';

 // Store possible delay values in an array
 var possibleDelays = [1000, 5000];
      
 function reload() {
   $.ajax(location.href)
    .done(function () {
       $("h1").text(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
       // Success! Do it again!
       setTimeout(reload, possibleDelays[Math.round(Math.random())]);
    }).fail(reload); // When there's an error, try again
  }

  // Initiate the process with an interval that is generated right here.
  setTimeout(reload, possibleDelays[Math.round(Math.random())]);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: Well, I've run your code in tampermonkey and once it starts running, it will either refresh after 1 second EVERY SINGLE TIME if the random number is 1 at the start, or 5 seconds EVERY SINGLE TIME if the random number is 5 at the start.

Comment: That's the full running version of the code I'm testing. I'm using tampermonkey and am just testing it on google.com.

Comment: I tested the code on tampermonkey but it's not refreshing at all.

Comment: It says unexpected token ;

Comment: It's not refreshing at all. It's just sitting there when I tested it out on google.

Comment: Are you testing it out in tampermonkey on google.com? I see that the console the logs prints out 1000 or 5000 on the first time it goes on google.com, but after that the website just sits there and doesn't refresh.

Comment: Well, i went to inspect and i can see in networks that it is refreshing...but the page isn't noticeably showing it...

Comment: Also after about 150 request the script goes crazy and tries to refresh the page every other millisecond...

Comment: @frosty Ok, I've tested this out now and it's working as it should. The key is not to rely on the old `interval` value, but to re-calculate it as needed. When you try this, you will see the time at each refresh. It may go by the same amount a few times in a row (there are only two choices after all), but it will change to the other time if you wait long enough.

Comment: @frosty Did you try it out?

Comment: No. But I've got it to work with the iframe. I just needed to put the random rolls inside the onload function, right on top of the settimeout function. Then it works. But thanks for trying to help anyways, I'll accept your answer.